# Toolbar buttons similar to Evernote iPad app

Tags: ios, ipad, uiwebview, ios6, uibutton

Can anybody suggest me how to create toggle buttons in UIWebView Keyboard's toolbar very similar to what Evernote application has when you edit a note. I know how to add buttons in that toolbar. I just want to know how can I create the buttons look like that. Can this be achieved using simple UISwitch?

This is what exactly I want to achieve.
[image: Buttons on UIWebView Keyboard's toolbar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with a `UIButton`. Either set the image for `UIControlStateSelected` on the button or do it in Interface Builder by changing the image for "Selected State Configuration". You can then toggle the button state by changing the `selected` property of it.

Ex:

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_on"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
button.selected = YES;
```

Comment: Ok thanks Hampus I think that should work. But one more problem, when I add buttons in that toolbar using [toolbar setItems:buttonsArray]; all buttons set left aligned. Do you know how can I center them same as what is shown in above image?

Comment: use flexible spaces: UIBarButtonItem *flexible = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil]